# read.delim2 and read.table gives two different results?

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I have a tab-delimited data:
When I use .table some data are missing from the table

```
df1 = read.table('data_groups.txt', sep='\t', header=T)
dim(df1)
```

gives me :

```
318 112
```

where as:

```
df2 = read.delim2('data_groups.txt', sep='\t', header=T)
dim(df2)
```

gives me :

```
507 112
```

Comment: By default, `read.table` has a `blank.lines.skip = TRUE` argument, which removes empty lines in the input, but `read.delim2` doesn't seem to have this argument. This might the reason for the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `quote=''` wll solve your issue

```
read.table('data_groups.txt', sep='\t', header=T, quote='')
```